# Can't get current location in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, jsx

I have a multilingual React app that needs to render content in a language based on the current pathname.
e.g.:
www.englishwebsite.com -> renders the app in English
www.frenchwebsite.com -> renders the app in French

To achieve this, I am trying to get the current pathname inside a class; but this keeps failing or giving me an undefined. In my code, I currently have no visual progress of what I've tried, but I did try to find a way to get the props and even 'location.pathname'.

Also, is this a correct way to render different languages? Keep in mind, I am new into React.

A quick example

```
App.js 
class App extends Component {   
   render() {
       return (
           <BrowserRouter>
               <div className='App'>
                   <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
       );
   }
}


Home.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export class Home extends Component {

render () {
    return (
        <div className='homecontent'>
           <div>
           // if site url is www.englishwebsite.com
           English content
           // else if site url is www.frenchwebsite.com
           French content
           </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hint: test value of `window.location.host`. The `pathname` starts after the `.com`

Comment: I would go with templates instead of this approach. Let the user select a language. Surround your static text with `[[[my text]]]` and have different templates that switch out the text based on language.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. That did the trick!

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I'm going to try your answer too, thanks!

Comment: Any time! There are libraries that do this for you that make your life easier. I can't remember the names of them sorry. Using templates and switching them dynamically allows you to write your components with out having any logic for rendering inside each of the components. Would be a hassle if you had hundreds, what if you had to change them?

Comment: True indeed. Will look for some libraries!

Answer (score -1):

Get the URL information from **window** object and store that in your State, with that you can create a switch case.